# CSS: display:inline-block not aligning divs correctly

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm having some trouble getting my divs to align correctly, though I know the basic idea is sound.

What I want is for the larger div (bound) to have the title, bonus, and image all on the same row, however currently the bonus appears below the title field. Any ideas?

The CSS in question:

```
.bound
{
   position:relative;
   z-index:1000; 
   border-style:solid; 
   border-width:1px; 
   padding:1%; 
   border-color:#0f0f0f; 
   border-radius:6px;
}

.event 
{
   border-style:none; 
   width:100%; 
   height:70px; 
   line-height: 60px;
   position: relative;
}

.title
{
   display:inline-block !important;
   height:100%;
   width:30%;
   min-width:250px;
   position: relative;
}

.bonus
{
   display:inline-block !important;
   height:100%;
   width:15%;
   min-width:200px;
   text-align:center;
   position: relative;
}

#click
{
   position:absolute; 
   width:100%; 
   height:60px; 
   z-index: 1;
}
```

A simplified version of the HTML:

```
<div id="bound">
    <div id="event">
        <a href="title link"><span id="click"></span></a>
        <img src="files/image.png" align="right">
        <div id="title">
            <span style="font-size:150%; font-weight:bold;">Title</span>
        </div>
        <div id="bonus">
            <span style="font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:#32CD32;">Bonus</span>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your CSS has `.event` but your HTML has `id=event` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because By default div is `display:block`. Use `display:inline-block` will display both in same line.

```
#event > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tbnstmq/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Hey there is small mistake. when `id` is used in styling thern `#` is used to refer its style. just change the `.` in the css to the `#` and this will work. Here is [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surajpalwe/L711j9wg/)

Answer (score 0):

make inline style `float:left` to title's span as:

```
<span style="font-size:150%; font-weight:bold;float:left">Title</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything in a single line just add (it's not recommended to use id for styling though):

```
#event > *{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3tbnstmq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think in css you have put '.' instead of '#' to the 'title class'. because from my point of view in your html you have used 'title' as a 'id' and in css you can apply style using '#'.

in that css class add 'float:left' attribute. also put your image and anchor tag in 'Div' and add them style 'float:left'.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
.title
{
   display:inline-block !important;
   height:100%;
   width:30%;
   min-width:250px;
   position: relative;
}

.bonus
{
   display:inline-block !important;
   height:100%;
   width:15%;
   min-width:200px;
   text-align:center;
   position: relative;
}
```

to this

```
#title
{

   height:100%;
   width:30%;
   min-width:250px;
   position: relative;
   float:left;
   border:solid blue 1px;
}

#bonus
{

   height:100%;
   width:15%;
   min-width:200px;
   text-align:center;
   position: relative;
   float:left;
   border:solid blue 1px;
}
```

it must be '#' not '.' since you are trying to align elements inside two div and in your code you used ID and add float to make it aline

hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did wrong in few points like you used id='title' and written styling for class '.title', because of that it's not implementing. And if you just want to put that in a line then put 
    #title { float: left; }
    #bonus { float: left; }
In current styling the #title div and #bonus div taking 100% width that's why not in a line.